# Create a new element and append a clone to this element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initial situation looks like this:

```
<div id="bigDiv">
    <div><input type="file"/></div>
</div>
```

Desired result after cloning:

```
<div id="bigDiv">
    <div><input type="file"/></div>
    <div><input type="file"/></div>
</div>
```

I've tried following statement:

```
var elm = $('#bigDiv :input[type=file]').change(function(event) {
    console.log('changed');
    $('#bigDiv :input[type=file]').eq(0).clone(true).val('').appendTo('#bigDiv');
});
```

This works. My Question is, how can I append this new file input element into a new div element, which has to be created before too? (See desired result above)

I think my jQuery statement is improvable too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to clone the entire `div`. Try this:

```
var elm = $('#bigDiv :input[type=file]').change(function(event) {
    var $newDiv = $('#bigDiv div').first().clone(true).appendTo('#bigDiv');
    $('input[type="file"]', $newDiv).val('');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KrnGr/)

Comment: @samitha that is not creating the DOM structure the OP wanted. It puts the file inputs in the same `div`, not in their own ones.

Comment: Thank you Rory, the clone-process should be triggered onChange.. (jsfiddle -> extra button)

Answer (score 0):

One liner: http://jsfiddle.net/6QL3k/2/, works on created too

```
var elm = $('#bigDiv').on('change',' :input[type=file]',function(event) {
    console.log('changed');
     $(this).clone().appendTo($(this).parent().parent()).wrap('<div></div>');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6QL3k/

```
  var elm = $('#bigDiv :input[type=file]').change(function(event) {
      console.log('changed');
      var next = $(this).clone();
      var wrapNext = $('<div></div>');
      wrapNext.append(next);
      $(this).parent().after(wrapNext);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way without using clone

```
var div = $("#bigDiv").find("div").first().html();
$("input").first().after(div);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/As2a2/)**